# Fixed point theorem of continuous functions-visualized.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

We all know the theorem that If $f:[a,b]\to [a,b]$ is continuous,then $f$ has a fixed point $c\in [a,b]$.The proof is very easy,nothing special about that.But how to visualize this theorem,I could not convince myself graphically that this should happen.It is not looking very obvious to me even if the proof is quite simple.In a word I am looking for a visualization of this theorem i.e.a way to interpret it geometrically.Can someone help me on this?

I have though of something.Consider the graph of the function,plot the interval $[a,b]$on both the $x$ and $y$ axes.We can think of a square bounded by $x=a,x=b,y=a,y=b$ with the line $y=x$ as one of its diagonals.now the point on the graph of $f$ corresponding to $x=a$ must lie somewhere on the vertical line $x=a$.If $f(a)=a$ then we are done.Otherwise,since the function is continuous,it must be drawn without lifting the pen(as the domain is an interval).now if we keep plotting points on the graph corresponding to points starting from $a$ to $b$,then the curve has to cut the line $y=x$ at some point.Otherwise the function will remain at one side of the diagonal of the square(in one of the right triangular regions) and at least an end point of the diagonal must lie on the curve either at $x=a$ or $x=b$ giving the respective one as a fixed point.[image: Figure]

Comment: What about creating pictures from the proof?

Comment: Good idea,even just now I though one thing,I am adding it in my question.

Comment: Geometrically the idea is: *a continuous graph joining the opposite sides of a square has to cross the diagonal*.

Comment: exactly what I was thinking of,in extreme case,the curve has to intersect the end point $(a,f(a))$ of the diagonal.

Comment: You have to touch the line at some point to reach the other side

Comment: exactly....................